# How do I get the ‘program name’ (invocation location) in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line

I want the equivalent of $PROGRAM_NAME in Ruby, or ARGV[0] in C-likes, for Node.js. When I have a Node script that looks something like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log(process.argv[0])
```

… I get “node” instead of the name of the file that code is saved in. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use this (if called from your main.js file):

```
var path = require('path');
var programName = path.basename(__filename);
```

Or this, anywhere:

```
var path = require('path');
var programName = path.basename(process.argv[1]);
```

Comment: I really wish there was a more direct way, but the latter seems to answer my question. I'm still afraid of edge-cases that it seems not to cover, but I can't pinpoint one, so I'm accepting this. (=

Answer (score 1):

Use __filename? It returns the currently executing script.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename

Comment: That, however, won't tell me what it was *invoked* as. That will fail with symlinks, or with wrapper-scripts such as those npm uses, or anything else of that flavour.

Answer (score -2):

For working with command line option strings check out the [optimist](https://github.com/substack/optimist) module by Substack. Optimist will make your life much easier.

```
var inspect = require('eyespect').inspector();
var optimist = require('optimist')
var path = require('path');
var argv = optimist.argv
inspect(argv, 'argv')
var programName = path.basename(__filename);
inspect(programName, 'programName')
```

To install the needed dependencies:

```
npm install -S eyespect optimist
```

Comment: -1 for pushing your own modules, without declaration; not to mention that I clearly asked for a way to do so *in Node.js*, without pulling in extra modules. (That said, Optimist *is* great; it's just inapplicable in this situation. NPM is not always the solution, nor always an option.)